# Microsoft SQL Master Data Services 2012 Importing data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Well i have searched as much as i can, but didn't find any exactly videos or posts about the importing data into Microsoft SQL MDS 2012. As much i have saw on youtube there is no such video. But only a slightly video on MSDN about how to insert data with SSIS, but i need to insert data with SQL statements in exact table and run data batch how to do that, can anyone show it. How to do that ? In which table to insert it ? How to run the batch that upload the data (if that' is neccessary). As far as i know in MSSQL MDS 2008R2 the data was inserted in 3 tables (mdm.tblStgMember,mdm.tblStgMemberAttribute and mdm.tblStgRelationship), but in this versio insertion is different as i know from information from MSDN, i'm new to this and i cant' test what i need. And in 2012MDS as far as i know insertion goes only in one table, please help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the answer myself. In 2012 MDS the data insertion process is going to leaf members tables. So you need insert to exactly that leaf member table the data what you need. I hope it will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add up here.

MSDN says:

> *"The staging process has changed since SQL Server 2008 R2. The staging process that was used in SQL Server 2008 R2 is no longer
>   available in the Master Data Manager web application; however it is
>   still available in SQL Server Management Studio."*

So here are some good sources I found using 2012 version:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/hh802433.aspx#
- http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/DBI204

And this video as part from SQL2012 Training Kit:

**http://ak.channel9.msdn.com/ch9/01ef/8dc4f2ea-6974-4f12-a77b-1ad1b67d01ef/SQL11UPD05REC04_Source.wmv**

(http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27721 - Complete SQL Kit download)